# googleapp script sendmail body variable issue

Tags: google-apps-script, sendmail

I have a "problem" sending some email. Sending emails works perfectly fine but whenever my variable contains more than 4 lines, the others lines stays on the same 4th line.

This is what is included in my body:

var message = "Hello "+first_name+" there are "+numofreq+" requests that needs to be deployed:\n\n"+ritmtodeploy+" \nThanks";

The variable i'm talking about is +ritmtodeploy+

Here is it's content:

Marc - xxx
Anto - xxx
Al - xxx
R- new sites: xxxx
Mar - ligne bidon
Mar - test

This is the logger.log output for my message variable :

Hello al there are 6 requests that needs to be deployed:

Marc - xxx
Anto - xxx
Al - xxx
R- new sites: xxxx
Mar - ligne bidon
Mar - test

Thanks

And this is what I get in the email:

Hello al there are 6 requests that needs to be deployed:

Marc - xxx
Anto - xxx
Al - xxx
R- new sites: xxxx Mar - ligne bidon Mar - test

Thanks

I can't figure out why this is happening? Is there a limit that I am not aware of?

Many thanks in advance if you know!

Comment: What does you sendMail command look like?

Comment: MailApp.sendEmail({
  to: dsc_tech_email,
  subject: subject,
  body: message,
  noReply: true
 });

Looks like this.

Comment: Please provide [mcve]